# Reactjs how to change the state of a component from a different component

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, backbone.js, reactjs

I have a react component, lets call it as component 1

```
define([..., /path/component_2.jsx], function(..., Component2) {
   var Component1 = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
         return {.......};
      },

      componentDidMount: function() {
          .......
          dates = ....;
          Component2.setState({dates: dates});
      }
       render: function() { return (<div ...></div>) }
   });
}
```

As you can see, I am calling the Component2.setState in this component. But I am getting an error like setState is not a function. I tried this with defining a custom function instead of setState function in component 2 and calling this function from component 1, but I am getting the same error, 'is not a function'.

And component 2:

```
define([..., ], function(...) {
   var Component2 = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
         return {.......};
      },

      render: function() { return (<div ...></div>) }
   });
}
```

So I guess in reactjs we calls a component only for rendering something (React DOM elements)? and cannot change the component state?

If so how can I change a state of a component from a different component which is not a child or parent of first?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Components don't publicly expose their state. It's also important to remember that the state is scoped to the *instance* of components, not their definition.

To communicate between components, you could roll your own event subscription service.

```
var events = new EventEmitter();

// inside Component1
events.emit('change-state', newState);

// inside Component2
events.on('change-state', function(state) {
  this.setState(state);
});
```

However, this will quickly become difficult to manage.

A more sensible solution is to use [Flux](https://facebook.github.io/flux/). It allows you to explicitly manage the state of your entire application and subscribe to changes in different bits of the state, within your components. It's worth trying to wrap your head around it.

The component that wants to communicate should dispatch an action and this action will be responsible for changing something in the stores, your other component should subscribe to that store and can update its state based on the change.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a shared state between the two component. 
You can build a "mixin" like that

```
app.mixins.DateMixin = {
   getInitialState: function () 
      return {
          dates: []
         }
      }
};
```

and then in you components you can include this mixins using the mixins array

```
define([..., /path/component_2.jsx], function(..., Component2) {
   var Component1 = React.createClass({

      mixins: [app.mixins.DateMixin],

      getInitialState: function() {
         return {.......};
      },

      componentDidMount: function() {
          .......
          dates = ....;
          this.setState({dates: dates});
      }
       render: function() { return (<div ...></div>) }
   });
}

define([..., ], function(...) {

   mixins: [app.mixins.DateMixin],

   var Component2 = React.createClass({
      getInitialState: function() {
         return {.......};
      },

      render: function() { return (<div ...></div>) }
   });
}
```

Now your components share the "dates" state and you can change/check it in both of them. 
NB: you can also share methods with in the same way by writing into a mixin component.

Edit: I suggest you to visit this website http://simblestudios.com/blog/development/react-mixins-by-example.html

Comment: React plans to [eventually deprecate mixins](https://facebook.github.io/react/blog/2015/03/10/react-v0.13.html), so going forward it's best to try and find solutions that don't rely on them.

Comment: @DanPrince really? hmm.. just read the nice document about mixins that rakwaht posted

Comment: It's not about to happen in the next version, but the React team are working towards finding a better solution. There's a discussion  [here](https://github.com/facebook/react/issues/4023).

Comment: @DanPrince here I post the answer of the owner of the repo. "We're not ready to deprecate mixins because we don't have good replacements for all of their use cases. When we do, we'll probably move towards deprecating mixins and React.createClass, but that is at least months away." However I think you are right that it's better to find out another way to do it but for now this is the only pattern that I know to solve this kind of problems

Comment: Bear in mind, that was posted on the 9th of June, which was 4 months ago. Based on how much changed in React v0.14, I wouldn't be surprised if they were deprecated in the next few versions.

Comment: I get your point but still I found what you explained above difficult to mange on huge application. Are there other solutions?

Comment: Hi guys, I tried Prince's solution with event emitters and on date_change_event and upon that I am firing a callback function. Inside the function I am doing the actions. It is working fine. Thank you Prince. And I know the mixin also will work in this situation and easy to implement, but I didn't tried it. Thanks rakwaht for suggesting the mixins.